# Is it possible to tie an email submit button to a specific row in a repeating table?

Tags: infopath

I want to be able to use the repeating table funtion to keep a history or correspondence on a specific item.   I start with an InfoPath form created for SharePoint. Now I want to be able to use email id, date, and comment fields to track comments in the form, but everytime I set up the submit button to email in a repeating table it only sends to the first row email.
The repeating table recreates each column including the button, but even thougth I have a different name in that new column it goes back to the original name from the first columm to email.
Any Ideas how I can get this to work, or find/create a different style work around?